# What algorithm or software can I use to calculate tiles placement?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, tile

My father is currently working on his new house and he is now ready to get to the floor tiles. He asked me what he called a "computer sciences" question but I guess it is more mathematics and algorithmics.

The problem is the following : let's imagine a given space of work (for instance 10x5 meters) and tiles from different sizes :

- 50cm x 50cm
- 30cm x 50cm
- 30cm x 50cm

There's a suggested pattern which is built around these 3 types of tiles which form kind of an "L" and I want to repeat this pattern as much as possible in the room for aesthetic.

My question is : How can I optimize tiles placement to fit the maximum number of full tiles without cutting too much of them on the edge? Is there a software or a given data-structure for this kind of problem?

I don't have a given language (even if Python is welcomed) but my goal is to be able to draw the room with all tiles placed to fit the maximum number of uncut tiles! Hope I made it clear

Sorry if it's duplicate but I can't seem to find decent keywords

Comment: Might better be asked on SE Home Improvement.

Comment: sounds like an optimization problem... try dynamic programming first

Comment: Create a cost function and then do simulated annealing.

Comment: You can also refer to Pythagorean tiling. The pattern you are asking is similar to Pythagorean tiling. I am sure you will find much articles relating same. Here is the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_tiling

Comment: You need to show us the pattern that you're wanting to replicate. Also, you need to specify the spacing between the tiles.

Answer (score 1):

We can't give you a strict solution, because you haven't completely specified the problem.  You haven't given us the trade-off evaluation between maintaining the desired "L" shape and cutting a tile.  You also haven't specified the "L"; there are several possibilities.  For instance:

```
 +-----+
 | 3x5 |
 |     +---+
 |         |
 | 5x5  5x3|
 +---------+

 +---+
 |5x3|
 |   +-----+
 |         |
 | 5x5  5x3|
 +---------+
```

I recommend that you look up the field of [tesselations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation); the most comprehensive references (IMHO) are from [Darrah Chavey](https://www.beloit.edu/computerscience/faculty/chavey/catalog/).

The simplest beginning is to simply "spoon" your "l" shapes on their natural diagonal:

```
       +-----+  ... and upward to the wall
       |     |
       |     +---+
 +-----+         |
 | 3x5 |         |
 |     +---+-----+
 |         |
 | 5x5  5x3|
 +---------+
```

Another is that you can form two of your "L" shapes, rotate one a half-turn, and join them into a hexagon with two concave corners.  This hexagon will tile the plane similarly:

```
   +---------+
   |         |
   |         |
 +-+---+     |
 | 3x5 |     |
 |     +---+-+
 |         |
 | 5x5  5x3|
 +---------+
```

For such a large space, you will probably want to choose a repeating pattern the works well for your specific space dimensions, and then either

1. Start in one corner and propagate across the room, dealing with the opposite edges as you see fit;
2. Start in the center, adjust a little to hit the walls nicely, but handle the edges more equitably;
3. Align with the edges and work toward the middle, cutting a few tiles to produce a differentiated center feature.